# Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 1947467776) (tried to allocate 65488 bytes)

Tags: php, function

I am running a very simple function but getting memory timeout issues, any suggestions?

```
function getSum($value)
{
    return  getsum($value) + "58";
}

echo getSum(5) // I would expect it to show 63
```

But instead I get:

```
Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 1947467776) (tried to allocate 65488 bytes) in C:\Users\
```

Comment: lol its a loop that will never end until something crashes

Comment: You're creating an infinite loop - the function will call itself indefinitely. You just need to `return  $value + 58;`

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO It works on my (Turing) machine.

Comment: Also be careful, you're adding a string of "58" and not the number 58

Comment: @craig1231 with php it doesnt matter

Answer (score 6):

This is entering in an infinite loop because getSum() is always being called recursively.

You should do this:

```
 function getSum($value)
{
    return  $value + 58;
}
```

Comment: haha! duh! sorry guys.. of course.. lol brain fart over here.. this is obviously a simplified version of an abstract class I am working on, and I couldn't figure this out.. time to get some coffee and wake up!